# How to import null string as null mark in csv files using ssis package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

How to import null string as null mark in csv files using ssis package

```
csv file have values : 
id |name |deptno | sal
1  |a    |NULL   |NULL
2  |b    |NULL    |NULL
3  |c    |NULL    |NULL
NULL|d   |10      |NULL
```

type of file : csv comma separated values
[image]

```
[![enter code here][2]][2]


Target table emp : 
id |name |deptno | sal
1  |a    |NULL   |NULL
2  |b    |NULL    |NULL
3  |c    |NULL    |NULL
NULL|d   |10      |NULL
```

Here i am not getting db null values  and its getting string null values
[image]
[image]

how to resolve null values issue in ssis package side

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an SSDT installation handy, so I can't add any screenshot for this, and the expressions will just be "close". They'll likely need some tweaking to work.

In your `Data Flow Task`, between the source and the destination, add a `Derived Column Transformation`. Add two new columns. Call them something similar to the two columns you're having trouble with; say `dept_no_clean` and `sal_clean`. Leave them set to `<Add as new column>`.

For the `Expression`, you'll want to tell SSIS to convert the string value `'NULL'` to an actual NULL, otherwise, just pass the numeric value (I'm guess at data types here. You'll want to set them to be whatever is correct for your data. I'll use an `INTEGER` for `dept_no` and a decimal for `sal`.):

```
sal_clean      sal="NULL" ? NULL(DT_NUMERIC, 18, 2) : (DT_NUMERIC, 18, 2)sal

dept_no_clean  dept_no="NULL" ? NULL(DT_I4) : (DT_I4)dept_no
```

The expression is an `IF/THEN/ELSE` conditional. And, again, might not be 100% correct as written.

Finally, edit your destination. Map the two new, derived columns to the corresponding columns in the destination table.